# Tell ido to ignore all star buffers except for some

Tags: emacs, buffer, ido

Normally I want `ido` to ignore all *non-user* buffers, i.e. all buffers which start with a `*`. I have achieved this using the following setting:

```lisp
(setq ido-ignore-buffers '("\\` " "^\*"))
```

However, this poses a problem when working with a shell or an interpreter, e.g. `ielm`, where the interaction buffer is named `*ielm*`. Obviously adding all buffers to be ignored manually is not really an option because the list can get quite long with a lot of different emacs packages loaded. I know about `C-a` which disabled the ignore pattern from within `ido`, however, I don't want to hit `C-a` every time I switch to an `ielm` buffer.

My question is:

> Is there some variable which allows to specify buffers which ido should **not** ignore (although they match the *normal* ignore list)? Or is there some other approach for solving this?

Comment: You can possibly build the regexp,  not to ignore \*ielm\* for ido-ignore-buffers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The list that the `ido-ignore-buffers` variable points to may contain not only regular expressions but also functions (any mix of them, actually). It's easy to provide a function to filter out all non-user buffers except `*ielm*`:

```lisp
(defun ido-ignore-non-user-except-ielm (name)
  "Ignore all non-user (a.k.a. *starred*) buffers except *ielm*."
  (and (string-match "^\*" name)
       (not (string= name "*ielm*"))))

(setq ido-ignore-buffers '("\\` " ido-ignore-non-user-except-ielm))
```

Here's an example of having multiple unignored buffer names:

```lisp
(setq my-unignored-buffers '("*ielm*" "*scratch*" "*foo*" "*bar*"))

(defun my-ido-ignore-func (name)
  "Ignore all non-user (a.k.a. *starred*) buffers except those listed in `my-unignored-buffers'."
  (and (string-match "^\*" name)
       (not (member name my-unignored-buffers))))

(setq ido-ignore-buffers '("\\` " my-ido-ignore-func))
```

An interesting example of using ignore functions can be found among comments in the `ido.el` source code (I've removed `;;` at the beginning of each line):

```lisp
(defun ido-ignore-c-mode (name)
  "Ignore all c mode buffers -- example function for ido."
  (with-current-buffer name
    (derived-mode-p 'c-mode)))
```

Basically, once you've got buffer name, you can do any checking/ignoring you want.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I wanted!

Comment: Can you please add an example with a list of exceptions?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: Exactly! Thank you very much!